# Click event on tr doesn't work when using table fixed header a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the [tablefixed header](http://www.tablefixedheader.com/) jQuery plugin.

This plugin is working properly, but I want a function to run `onclick` on `tr`, so I am putting an `onclink` event in `tr` of  `tbody` in `table` but its not working, whereas if I put the same `onclink` event in `tr` of `thead` section of `table` this works.

Do I need any modifications in jQuery (while I even don't know what kind of modification) or something else to run the function with `onclick` event?

**EDITED :**

Here I want to tell you one more thing that chrome property inspector is displaying `tr` `onclick` event of `thead` section (as I put `onclick` event in `thead` section) but if I put any thing in `tr` of `tbody` its not displaying it.

**jsfiddle**
sorry it took time to create fiddle this is http://jsfiddle.net/avnesh/jE42w/1/

Comment: Show your code. Or make some jsFiddle testcase.

Comment: make a jsfiddle with your code , and we can use the plugin code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reviewed jsfiddle link. Try to use this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#resizable').fixheadertable({ 
    caption     : 'My employees', 
    colratio    : [150,80,200,100,100],
    height      : 100,
    width       : 400,
    zebra       : true,
    sortable    : true,
    sortedColId : 1, 
    sortType    : ['integer', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'date'],
    dateFormat  : 'm/d/Y',
    //pager       : true,
    //rowsPerPage : 10,
    resizeCol   : true
});  

    $('#resizable tr td').live('click'  , function(){
        alert("YES");
    });


    });
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

$('#fixmyheader tbody tr').click(function(){alert(123)})

Comment: Here I want to tell you one more thing that chrome property inspector is displaying tr onclick event of thead section(as I put onclick event in thaed sectoin) but if i put any thing in tr of tbody its not displaying it.

Comment: Sorry, I posted with reference to the fixed header table in this url
http://www.tablefixedheader.com/demonstration/. Paste the above code in the console and check it. In your case you must replace the id with your table id

Comment: yes i did it properly as changing the id but it was not working